# How to resolve Node.js: "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, npm, enoent

I have a Node.js web application currently running on a server successfully. Now I'm trying to set up a local copy on my *development* server.

I currently have Node.js, NPM and MongoDB Installed just like what I have in production server. However, the error below occurs when I try to start the Node.js server.

What could be causing this issue?

```
cd ~/node/nodeapp
node app.js
```

Output:

```
fs.js:640
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/embah/node/nodeapp/config/c
onfig.json'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/embah/node/nodeapp/config/config.js:4:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/embah/node/glorby/app.js:13:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: It's complaining about a missing file. Do you have "/home/embah/node/nodeapp/config/c
onfig.json" in the correct location in your system?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Your app is expecting to find a file at `/home/embah/node/nodeapp/config/config.json` but that file does not exist (which is what `ENOENT` means). So you either need to create the expected directory structure or else configure your application such that it looks in the correct directory for `config.json`.

Answer (score 77):

After going through so many links and threads and getting frustrated over and over again, I went to the basics and boom! it helped. I simply did:

```
npm install
```

I don't know, but it might help someone :)

Comment: This may work for some, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Not as simple as my solution--computer rebooted, opened powershell in c:\windows\system, and I didn't realize I wasn't in my project directory!

Comment: I too faced the same issue & it worked for me too. Could anyone please explain why is it so? I know that npm's searching for some directory which it didn't find, but why?

Comment: Oddly `npm install` resulted in the same error for a completely new install, but `npm update` worked, then subsequent `npm install` worked too!

Comment: not sure why but this worked for me, maybe you can try this as a first go and if you are lucky you will be done in few instants

Answer (score 22):

Regarding:

> 92% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open....

If anyone faced to such an error, you should do followings:

1. you should check if the file path is correct in the *angular.json* file.

   "scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
   ],
2. you should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and rerun the project.

Comment: Better check the path relative to angular.json config file. for me I had to add root folder name as well. "scripts": [
          "../MYROOTFOLDER/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "../MYROOTFOLDER/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ],

Answer (score 21):

[olleh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260643/how-to-resolve-node-js-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory/50891794#50891794) worked, because `npm install` will create a *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* directory in the current path where it is executed. So, while using the *file server system module*, the below declaration locate files from the top level directory of `node_modules`.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
```

Answer (score 15):

In my case the issue was caused by using a file path starting at the directory where the script was executing rather than at the root of the project.

My directory stucture was like this:
projectfolder/
├── package.json
├── scriptFolder/
│   ├── myScript.js

And I was calling `fs.createReadStream('users.csv')` instead of the correct `fs.createReadStream('scriptFolder/users.csv')`

Answer (score 12):

If you have the same error while using Express.js in your project this worked for me:

In my project, when I ran an Express.js application, I noticed that the current working directory was the root directory of the project (while I was trying to read a file that was located in the script's directory).
It could not run the file since `process.cwd() !== __dirname`.

You can check it out and console log `process.cwd()` in the script you are trying to read the JSON file with.

I just changed the path to:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}\\FILENAME`);
```

Answer (score 7):

I solved this error by simply creating a blank file at that location for which I got the error. If you are getting the error for a directory, you can try by also creating an empty directory.

Answer (score 6):

I also had this issue, because I had another console window open that was running the application and I was attempting to rerun `yarn start` in another console window.

The first [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) executing prevented the second from writing. So I just killed the first process and it worked.

Comment: Had this exact issue because of an issue with VS Code

Answer (score 6):

I was facing this issue with `ng-package.json` file, while creating a plugin. I found out I was providing the wrong path in `angular.json`. Fixed my file path, issue was resolved.

May be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the issue occurred after I switched from a Git branch to another, references to some old files remained in the scripts inside the "node_modules/.cache" directory.

Deleting the "node_modules", "build" directories and "package-lock.json" file and then issuing the "npm install" command has fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thank you. Deleting the package-lock.json file and then running "npm install" helped solve my issue. My project had a local project dependency and I had recently deleted that second project's folder then re-cloned the repository.

Answer (score 5):

If there isn't any layout folder, just use it like this in your routing:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('something', { layout: false });
})
```

Here change something with your folder name.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your *angular.json* file has the "style" and "scripts" array as below **(for Angular 12 and above)**:

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
        ],
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ]
```

Once this is done, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and then `ng serve`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if anyone would see this, but I'll say my answer.

**First** you need to be in the app directory that you created with the following command:

```
npx create-react-app [app-name]
```

Next run:

```
sudo npm install
```

to make it install all dependencies from

> package.json

Then run:

```
sudo npm start
```

and make sure to run them with the **sudo** command, because sometimes it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: I was fighting through an issue with it not being able to write to `/private/var/folders` on mac. Ran it sudo, and it worked... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a helpful link on the *multer* GitHub page](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/513).

But for me, I also have to create a public folder in the server folder. It's like `-cb(null,'public/')`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `__dirname`:

```
const string = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/file.json", "utf8");
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the *PM2_HOME* environment variable on the system level and now it works all right.

Comment: Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64648421/edit) in your answer, e.g., by adding some references? (But ***** ***without*** ***** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

If you're coding with TypeScript, remember that the transpiled-JS folder is where JavaScript would be searching for your file and will definitely not be able to find your html-file; hence such error.

Therefore, you'd need to copy the file into the transpiledJS folder for it to be located.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was not adding `/` before the path. Correct path: `/Users/mee/Documents/file_name.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you see this issue in the following scenario.

Let's assume that you have a folder structure like *node-projects* (folder) → my-blog (folder) → my-blog (folder where the actual project exists), but you are in the `my-blog` directly, and it is an immediate child of `node-project`. Try to run your command in that directory.

As the project is present in `my-blog` that is an immediate child of `my-blog`. So, in this case, it searches your *config.json* file in `my-blog` (which is an immediate child of `node-projects`) rather than finding the *config.json* file in `my-blog` that is an immediate child of `my-blog`.

Just transfer your directory by hitting the command `cd my-blog` in your terminal and that's it. The problem is resolved!

Answer (score 1):

for me running

```
npm cache verify
```

indicated that some file is corrupted and run the following command

```
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/Mac/.npm"
```

did the trick. I assume the 2nd command will be your PC specific.

Answer (score 0):

It’s happened with me. I deleted some CSS files by mistake and then copied back. This error appeared at that time. So I restarted all my [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) images and other servers and then it went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

`import { Object } from '../config/env';`

gave me the error.

I solved it with change the address like this:

`import { Object } from './../config/env';`

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
npm run scss
npm run start
```

in that order in the terminal solved the issue for me.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some information about what those commands do (or are supposed to do).

Answer (score 0):

I work with Visual Studio Code, Git and Nx and often have the problem that Visual Studio Code performs an auto staging.

In combination with Nx, it comes very often to problems. Simply unstaging the files in Visual Studio Code often helps.

Comment: What is "nrwl"? Isn't it the short name of the company (Narwhal Technologies)? Do you mean Nx, Nx Cloud, or Nx Console?

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, in my project, I always get this error first time I add/remove a package, but then I run the same command again and it **works on the second run**.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error while uninstalling Bootstrap from the project, so I just deleted the script and style from file *angular.json*.

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
 "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
          ]
```

Cleared this to

```
"styles"  : [    ],
"scripts" : [    ]
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path and you're good to go.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35735677)

Answer (score -1):

I tried something and got this error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Website\Nodemailer\Nodemailer-application\views\layouts\main.handlebars'

The fix I got was to literally construct the directory as it is seen. This means labeling the items exactly as shown. It is weird that I gave the computer what it wanted.

Comment: Instead of "I tried something", can you explain what you were doing?  There are a lot of examples in the answers already. If yours is truly unique, try to explain why, so that it can stand out to someone looking for your answer among the others.