# npm package "watch" giving "no such file or directory" error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, webpack-dev-server, watch

Thanks in advance for helping me.

I want to create a **product build** on changes inside `src` directory. For that I used `watch` package of npm. Below is my "scripts" inside `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "watch 'npm run prod' src",
    "prod": "webpack --mode=production"
},
```

Now when I run `npm run dev` command. It gives me:

> **Error:** ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\projects\chatapp\run'

Answer (score 9):

If you are using **Windows**, you have to use `"` instead of `'` in `dev` command:

```
"dev": "watch \"npm run prod\" src"
```

It is also mentioned in [github.com/mikeal/watch#examples](https://github.com/mikeal/watch#examples):

> Note: Because Windows users may need to use double quotes rather than
>   single quotes they need to escape the them in npm scripts

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Will this script remain cross-platform after escaping the quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try with `npm install` maybe it solves or you can look at this thread as it seems similar issue [How to resolve Nodejs: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260643/how-to-resolve-nodejs-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory) 
and more specifically to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43260706/10928899

Comment: I tried by `npm install` and also tried to create prod and run folder. But not worked.