# running powershell command doesnt work in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

so i have a script that will run a power shell command, the main issue is that when i share this with other people it doesn't work but when i run it on my pc it does work.

```html
 fs.mkdirSync(response.filePaths[0] + "\\Workroom");
    fs.writeFileSync(response.filePaths[0] + "\\Workroom\\bot.js", "");
    fs.mkdirSync(response.filePaths[0] + "\\Workroom\\node_modules");
    require('winax');
    var run=new ActiveXObject('WSCRIPT.Shell').Run("npm install --prefix "+response.filePaths[0]+"\\Workroom"+" discord.js", 0);
    fs.writeFileSync("./path.txt", response.filePaths[0]);
```

Comment: I don't see any PowerShell in the sample code. `WSCRIPT.Shell` is not PowerShell.

Comment: ok i will try thanks

Comment: Is there any error message? If there isn't, try to get log files of Electron. Otherwise it will be hard to reason about the problem.

Comment: Oops i forgot to delete the question the problem wasnt about this

Comment: When running it it says npm err code enoent

Comment: It means "file not found". Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43260643/7571258