# How can I print multiple vars in alert box in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm newbie in JS and trying to show a alert box when user enters his/her "name-mail-message" in my html page. That alert box should contain information given by user. This is what I did;

```
<button type="submit" onclick="test()" class="form-control" id="submit-button" name="submit">Send</button>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function test() {
                                let inputName = document.getElementById("cf-name");
                                let inputMail = document.getElementById("cf-mail");
                                let inputMessage = document.getElementById("cf-message");

                                let total = (inputName.value);
                                alert(inputName.value + '\n' + inputMessage.value);
                            }
                        </script>
```

When I run it I get this output.

[image: This is the output of when I press "send" button]

How can I fix this issue? If you can help I would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to first get the `.value` for each input, instead of applying it for entire alert message.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="cf-name">
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="cf-mail">
<textarea placeholder="Msg" id="cf-message"></textarea>

<button type="submit" onclick="test()" class="form-control" id="submit-button" name="submit">Send</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test() {
    let inputName = document.getElementById("cf-name");
    let inputMail = document.getElementById("cf-mail");
    let inputMessage = document.getElementById("cf-message");

    let total = (inputName.value + '\n' + inputMail.value + '\n' + inputMessage.value);
    alert(total);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is name is defined as text and mail is defined as "mail" and message is defined as textarea in my code. When I try to do it like urs it gives me  an error. It says "Could not read source map for file:///C:/Users/ayber/Desktop/Template/js/bootstrap.min.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\ayber\Desktop\Template\js\bootstrap.min.js.map'"

Comment: @Roxox I have updated the answer with proper `input` types. As for the `ENOENT` error, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345566/9256189)

Answer (score 2):

You're adding up the DOM nodes. I would suppose you want to sum the *value* of those elements instead? If that's the case, access their value and store it in the variables as such:

```
function test() {
    const inputName = document.getElementById("cf-name").value;
    const inputMail = document.getElementById("cf-mail").value;
    const inputMessage = document.getElementById("cf-message").value;

    const total = (inputName + '\n' + inputMail + '\n' + inputMessage);
    alert(total);
}
```

Some additional notes:

- Use `const` instead of `let`, since those variables are not reassigned later in your code
- Avoid using `alert()`. Use `console.log()` instead, and open your browser dev tools to check the output

Comment: The problem is name is defined as text and mail is defined as "mail" and message is defined as textarea in my code. When I try to do it like urs it gives me  an error. It says "Could not read source map for file:///C:/Users/ayber/Desktop/Template/js/bootstrap.min.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\ayber\Desktop\Template\js\bootstrap.min.js.map'"

Comment: @Roxox It doesn't matter: the `value` property is native to all HTML input/select/textarea elements. The error you get is _not_ related to the code change but something with your bootstrap code.

Comment: please check my question again I updated it. When I try to print name and message there is no problem but when I try to print mail too its not printing anything

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the total variable in your alert

```
alert(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function test() {
    const inputName = document.getElementById("cf-name").value;
    const inputMail = document.getElementById("cf-mail").value;
    const inputMessage = document.getElementById("cf-message").value;
    alert(inputName +'\n' +inputMail +'\n'+ inputMessage +'\n');
}
```

Comment: The problem is name is defined as text and mail is defined as "mail" and message is defined as textarea in my code. When I try to do it like urs it gives me  an error. It says "Could not read source map for file:///C:/Users/ayber/Desktop/Template/js/bootstrap.min.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\ayber\Desktop\Template\js\bootstrap.min.js.map'"

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="cf-name">
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="cf-mail">
<input type="text" placeholder="Msg" id="cf-message">


<button type="submit" onclick="test()" class="form-control" id="submit-button" name="submit">Send</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test() {
    let inputName = document.getElementById("cf-name").value;
    let inputMail = document.getElementById("cf-mail").value;
    let inputMessage = document.getElementById("cf-message").value;

    let total = (inputName + '\n' + inputMail + '\n' + inputMessage);
    alert(total);
  }
</script>
```

and the result will be like if first input have 5 value second one have 6 and third one have 11 it will alert like that. [image]

Comment: The problem is name is defined as text and mail is defined as "mail" and message is defined as textarea in my code. When I try to do it like urs it gives me  an error. It says "Could not read source map for file:///C:/Users/ayber/Desktop/Template/js/bootstrap.min.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\ayber\Desktop\Template\js\bootstrap.min.js.map'"