# write a json file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs

[image]I have existing products.json data which consists of an array of data, I wanted to push a new json object on a post request. While the array of json objects gets updated but when I open the product.json file I don't see the newly added data in that file. And I get an error like this

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../data/products.json'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '../data/products.json'
}
```

**Folder Structure**

```
 controllers
     productController.js
models
     productModels.js 
data
   products.js
node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
server.js
```

**product controller file**

```
export const createProduct = async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const product = {
            userId: 'req.userId',
            id: 'req.id',
            title: 'req.title',
            body: 'req.body'
        }
        const newProduct = await create(product)
        res.writeHead(201, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        res.end(JSON.stringify(newProduct))
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

**product model file**

```
export const create = (product) => {
    const id = uuid()
    const newProduct = {...product, id}
    products.push(newProduct)

    writeDataToFile('../data/products.json', products)

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const newProduct = products.find(element => element.id = id)
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(newProduct)
        }, 1000)
    })
    return promise
}
```

**utils.js file**

```
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises';

export const writeDataToFile = async (filename, content) => {
    try {
        console.log(filename)
        console.log(process.cwd())
        await writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(content));      
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: ` While the array of json objects gets updated but when I open the product.json file`,What does it mean? Are you reading the data from file first?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260643/how-to-resolve-nodejs-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory/43260706
If it will not work in you then we find next solution for your question.

Comment: @DarshanRaval SO is asking a different question based on the scenario provided in the question.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I'm writing it. But the file itself is not showing any changes

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Sorry for that.

Comment: @DarshanRaval my server has no issues and I'm able to get the newly added as a response from the server. The problem is I'm not able to write the product.json file in my local folder using fs module of nodejs

Comment: @DarshanRaval Don't be sorry, it's ok.

Comment: try __dirname + ‘file path’

Comment: @mehta-rohan I get error, "ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the path is incorrect and thats why it is not updating the file.

```
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises';
import * as path from 'path';

import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

export const writeDataToFile = async (filename, content) => {
    try {
        console.log(filename)
        console.log(process.cwd());
        console.log(path.join(__dirname, filename)) // check if the path is correct
        await writeFile(path.join(__dirname, filename), JSON.stringify(content));      
     return 'File Updated';
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
}
```

You might need to await for the file operation to perform:

```
export const create = (product) => {
    const id = uuid()
    const newProduct = {...product, id}
    products.push(newProduct)

    await writeDataToFile('../data/products.json', products)

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const newProduct = products.find(element => element.id = id)
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(newProduct)
        }, 1000)
    })
    return promise
}
```

Comment: It's not working, I get error, "ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined".  I haven't made any mistake in importing the path module.

Comment: Yes, You are using es module system and it won't work with this directly. I have added the code check with this.

Comment: I can successfully write the file, the product.json file gets updated but now when I create a request the server sends a response "Error: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)"

Comment: Great, I believe you can ask a new question for that. As this question(initially what you have asked) is resolved, the answer should be marked and upvote for future reference.

Comment: @Approva I upvoted your answer now please help me because, What I see is, if the file doesn't get updated then the server sends a success response and if the file gets updated then the server returns  "Error: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)". So it's still part of the same question.

Comment: Can you add the function where you are sending the response. It seems you should send the response once the file is updated. You must be sending the response before the file gets updated.

Comment: I've already included that file, please take a look at the product controller file

Comment: I have udpated the code, the only thing is you need to wait for the write file function to update the file first and then send the data. What I see in the question code is your are sending the data not the file. Put debugger or console to check the flow of the methods. I'm sure you will find it.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, await writeDataToFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../data/products.json') also  I made the create function async but it still doesn't show any error in the console either neither I get any response from the server.

Comment: export const create = async (product) =>  {
    try{
        const id = uuid()
        const newProduct = {...product, id}
        products.push(newProduct)
        await writeDataToFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../data/products.json'), products)
        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const newProduct = products.find(element => element.id = id)
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(newProduct)
            }, 1000)
        })

        return promise
        
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238605/discussion-between-nishant-kumar-and-apoorva-chikara).

Comment: You are welcome  .