# Exception has occurred: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, server-side, nodemon

I am trying to debug my nodejs application but on running javascript debugger, it's showing error.

[image]

Here is the package.json file of my project.

```
{
   "name": "server",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "server side",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
     "start": "nodemon index.js",
     "debug": "nodemon --inspect index.js"
   },
   "keywords": [],
   "dependencies": {
     "aws-sdk": "^2.1069.0",
     "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
     "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
     "cors": "^2.8.5",
     "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
     "express": "^4.17.2",
     "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
     "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
     "mongoose": "^6.2.0",
     "multer": "^1.4.4",
     "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
   },
   "devDependencies": {},
   "author": "alkairis",
   "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Either you haven't installed the dependencies or you are missing a dependency in `package.json`.

Comment: No, I have installed all dependencies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve Nodejs: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260643/how-to-resolve-nodejs-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: No, I have already tried it

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using visual studio code

Answer (score 1):

In my case this issue was fixed when I run  `npm install` with sudo `sudo npm install`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using VSCode, I recommend to expose a port at inspect like this:

`nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 index.js`

and then you add something like this config to your `.vscode/launch.json`:

```js
{
              "type": "node",
              "request": "attach",
              "name": "Attach to Remote",
              "restart": true,
              "stopOnEntry": true,
              "port": 9229,
              "address": "0.0.0.0",
              "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
              "sourceMaps": true,
              "protocol": "inspector"
}
```

Comment: No it didn't worked