# Downloading a file into a specific directory results in errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, node.js-fs, enoent

First, I want to clarify that I am aware questions like this have been asked before (e.g. [How to resolve Node.js: "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260643/how-to-resolve-node-js-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)). But none of the ones I've found, seem to have a solution that fits my case. So, I am asking for solutions that would possibly be specific to my case.

I'm creating an archival tool for an art site I like. Basically I'm trying to use a URL to fetch an image (the URL is the base URL of the image), and then download it into a specific directory in my project.

I would expect `fs.createWriteStream(this.file_path, {flags: "w"})` in my below code to create the file if it doesn't exist, which is kind of the point--it isn't going to exist until I fetch the image from the URL and pipe it. I have two classes:

**my_project_root/lib/data/downloader.ts:**

```js
import * as https from "https";
import * as fs from "fs";
import axios from "axios";
import * as path from "path";

export class Downloader {
    private dirname: string = "";
    private artist: string = "";
    private dir_to_check: string = path.join(".", "downloaded", "artists");
    private file_path: string = path.join(".", "downloaded", "artists");
    private url: string = "";

    public constructor(dirname: string, artist: string, fileNameWithExt: string, url: string) {
        this.dirname = dirname;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.dir_to_check = path.join(this.dir_to_check, artist);
        this.file_path = path.join(dirname, this.file_path, artist, fileNameWithExt);
        this.url = url;
    }

    public async downloadImage(): Promise<boolean> {
        // Log paths for testing
        console.log(
            `
            __dirname: ${this.dirname}
            dir_to_create_if_not_exist: ${this.dir_to_check}
            file_path: ${this.file_path}
            artist: ${this.artist}
            `
        );

        // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
        const dirCreated = await this.dirCreateIfNotExists();
        if (!dirCreated) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            // Create writer
            const writer: any = fs.createWriteStream(this.file_path, {flags: "w"});

            // File was opened
            writer.on("open", () => {
                console.log(`File opened for writing: ${this.file_path}`);
            });

            const writeStreamPromise = new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
                // File is finished creating
                writer.on("finish", () => {
                    console.log(`Write stream finished for: ${this.file_path}`);
                    resolve(true); // Image download successful
                });
    
                // There was an error during file writing/creation
                writer.on("error", (error) => {
                    console.error(`Error during write: ${error}`);
                    resolve(false); // Image download failed
                });
            });

            // Fetch image
            const response = await axios({
                method: "GET",
                url: this.url,
                responseType: "stream",
                httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }),
                headers: {
                    "User-Agent": "my_user_agent_here",
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(`${process.env.key}:${process.env.username}`),
                },
            });

            response.data.pipe(writer);

            // Log the response status
            console.log(response.status); // Returns 200 (OK)

            // Return a promise that resolves when the write stream finishes
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                writer.on("finish", () => {
                    resolve(true); // Image download successful
                });
                writer.on("error", (error) => {
                    console.error("Error during download:", error);
                    resolve(false); // Image download failed
                });
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("downloadImage() error: " + error);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private async dirCreateIfNotExists(): Promise<boolean> {
        const targetDir: string = path.join(this.dir_to_check);
        try {
            // Directory creation successful
            await fs.promises.mkdir(targetDir, {recursive: true});
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            // Directory creation failed
            console.error("Error creating directory:", error);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**my_project_root/lib/process/download.ts:**
(Just showing relevant code for this one):

```js
this.contents_of_files.forEach(async contents => {
    contents = JSON.parse(contents);
    let data: any = contents[0];
    // Do stuff
    this.id = data.id;
    this.createdAt = data.created_at;
    this.updatedAt = data.updated_at;
    this.url = data.file.url;
    this.fileExt = data.file.ext;
    this.md5 = data.file.md5;
    this.artists = data.tags.artist;

    // Upload the image/file into each artist's folder(s) it's associated with
    await this.initiateDownload(dirname); // Dirname is my drive root all the way to my project root, for example: E:\my_project\
});
```

**My initiateDownload() method in 'download.ts':**

```js
async initiateDownload(dirname) {
    for (const artist of this.artists) {
        const file: string =`${this.md5}__${this.id}__${this.createdAt}__${this.updatedAt}.${this.fileExt}`;
        this.Downloader = new Downloader(dirname, artist, file, this.url);
        await this.Downloader.downloadImage();
    }
}
```

The error I'm receiving appears to have an issue with the file itself not existing yet, which is odd considering I'd expect it to create it if it doesn't exist.

The directory exists all the way to the `artists` folder/dir, and of course also the directories inside of that one that are named after the artist. For example: `my_project_root\downloaded\artists\artist_name\` exists. If I remove the dir `\artist_name\`, it will be created again when the script runs. So to me, it doesn't seem like a pathing issue.

I'm receiving an `ENOENT` error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\my_project_root\downloaded\artists\artist_name\file_name.jpg'
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting an `ENOENT` error when obviously it knows exactly where to create the directories. This seems like a conflict when trying to write to a file that it thinks should exist but obviously doesn't, right?

For further clarification, my `console.log()` statement at the top of my `downloadImage()` method returns this in the console:

```
__dirname: E:\my_project_root
dir_to_create_if_not_exist: downloaded\artists\artist_name
file_path: E:\my_project_root\downloaded\artists\artist_name\file_name.jpg
artist: artist_name
```

**EXTRA:**
I've just tried my codebase on another computer and it works just fine with no differences in code at all. Basically I just copied the project over and initialized npm for that project dir. The only difference is where on the other computer the project is located at. Is it possible this is a permissions issue with the project taking place on a secondary harddrive...?

Comment: Why are you trying to create a directory called `file_name.jpg`?  Surely you want to strip the filename off before you create the directory.

Comment: All instances of `fs.createWriteStream()` I've seen pass through the path with the file at the end of it. But that's to create the file not the directory. For the directory, I'm not trying to create a directory (folder) with the name of `file_name.jpg`.

Comment: But that is also my confusion, the ENOENT error seems to be pointing to a missing directory of `file_name.jpg` when it shouldn't be trying to view that as a directory, correct? It should be using that to create a file named `file_name.jpg` inside of `.....\artists\artist_name\`??

Comment: @quietWind01  The error suggests otherwise. You have the filename in the path you pass to `mkdir` ... But it still seems strange that `mkdir` throws an exception with the `{ recursive: true }` option, because it should create all missing directory along the path ... May it be a permission thing, that it cannot create one of the directories alogn the path?

Comment: That's what I am confused about, it should be doing one thing but the error is stating another... if I added the `w` flag to the mkdir method (giving writer permission to the directory itself) do you think that would solve my issue? createWriteStream has the `write` flag but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I should note that I *am* trying to follow the `fs` documentation. Also, I noticed my folders when I go into properties (Windows 11) are marked as read-only by default but when I change it to be write allowed, and then open the properties for that folder again, it goes back to being read only. I'm not sure if that could be the issue or not either.

Comment: No, your `dirCreateIfNotExists` is doing a `mkdir` for the entire file name, not for the directory part.

Comment: OMG, I see what you're talking about now. Yeah, that was actually the last thing I did just trying to see what would happen while trying to diagnose. Using `this.dir_to_check` on the `mkdir` function is how it was until I uploaded the code here and I just forgot to change it--the error doesn't change one bit using `this.dir_to_check` on `mkdir` like it's supposed to.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have edited my answer to reflect how it should be just to avoid confusion. However the issue is still somewhere else, the edited code is how it was when the error originally occurred now, and said `ENOENT` error is exactly the same as before. I should also mention that if I delete directory `artist_name`, the `mkdir` function knows where to create it, and does so... it's just not creating the file(s) inside of that dir. Sorry if I overexplain things.

Comment: You can't be getting the same ENOENT, because the previous one was from `mkdir`.  It  may be time for a new question.

Comment: The ENOENT error and path are the same, but now it just comes from `fs.createWriteSteam()`. But it throws the same error. It's just a different place it's being thrown at. Trust me I checked.

I updated the question again to include the exact error given.

Comment: I'm updating my question *again*... I just tried the code on a different PC and it works literally just fine. Now I'm more confused.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem ended up being my file name:

```js
async initiateDownload(dirname) {
    for (const artist of this.artists) {
        const file: string =`${this.md5}__${this.id}__${this.createdAt}__${this.updatedAt}.${this.fileExt}`;
        this.Downloader = new Downloader(dirname, artist, file, this.url);
        await this.Downloader.downloadImage();
    }
}
```

This:

```js
const file: string =`${this.md5}__${this.id}__${this.createdAt}__${this.updatedAt}.${this.fileExt}`;
```

This should have been obvious to me, but for some reason it wasn't; the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties contained formats with characters (e.g. `:`) that are illegal for file names. Simply setting the file name itself as the md5 hash string resolved all issues:

```js
const file: string = `${this.md5}.${this.fileExt}`;
```