# Error in Next.js,shadcn-ui on running npm run dev-> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:/components.json'

Tags: next.js14, enoent, shadcnui

[View error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHJwF.png)

Error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:/components.json' Import
> trace for requested module:
> ./app/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfcZ9.png).rules[11].oneOf[12].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfcZ9.png).rules[11].oneOf[12].use[3]!./app/globals.css
> ./app/globals.css

As per the error, it lies in the global.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 0 0% 100%;
    --foreground: 222.2 84% 4.9%;

    --card: 0 0% 100%;
    --card-foreground: 222.2 84% 4.9%;

    --popover: 0 0% 100%;
    --popover-foreground: 222.2 84% 4.9%;

    --primary: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;
    --primary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --secondary: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --secondary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;

    --muted: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --muted-foreground: 215.4 16.3% 46.9%;

    --accent: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --accent-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;

    --destructive: 0 84.2% 60.2%;
    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --border: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;
    --input: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;
    --ring: 222.2 84% 4.9%;

    --radius: 0.5rem;
  }

  .dark {
    --background: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --card: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --card-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --popover: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --popover-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --primary: 210 40% 98%;
    --primary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;

    --secondary: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --secondary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --muted: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --muted-foreground: 215 20.2% 65.1%;

    --accent: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --accent-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --destructive: 0 62.8% 30.6%;
    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --border: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --input: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --ring: 212.7 26.8% 83.9%;
  }
}

* {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  font-family: var(--font-poppins)
}

.filter-grey {
  filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(47%) sepia(0%) saturate(217%)
    hue-rotate(32deg) brightness(98%) contrast(92%);
}

/* ========================================== TAILWIND STYLES */
@layer utilities {
  .wrapper {
    @apply max-w-7xl lg:mx-auto p-5 md:px-10 xl:px-0 w-full;
  }

  .flex-center {
    @apply flex justify-center items-center;
  }

  .flex-between {
    @apply flex justify-between items-center;
  }

  /* TYPOGRAPHY */
  /* 64 */
  .h1-bold {
    @apply font-bold text-[40px] leading-[48px] lg:text-[48px] lg:leading-[60px]  xl:text-[58px] xl:leading-[74px];
  }

  /* 40 */
  .h2-bold {
    @apply font-bold text-[32px] leading-[40px] lg:text-[36px] lg:leading-[44px] xl:text-[40px] xl:leading-[48px];
  }

  .h2-medium {
    @apply font-medium text-[32px] leading-[40px] lg:text-[36px] lg:leading-[44px] xl:text-[40px] xl:leading-[48px];
  }

  /* 36 */
  .h3-bold {
    @apply font-bold text-[28px] leading-[36px] md:text-[36px] md:leading-[44px];
  }

  .h3-medium {
    @apply font-medium text-[28px] leading-[36px] md:text-[36px] md:leading-[44px];
  }

  /* 32 */
  .h4-medium {
    @apply font-medium text-[32px] leading-[40px];
  }

  /* 28 */
  .h5-bold {
    @apply font-bold text-[28px] leading-[36px];
  }

  /* 24 */
  .p-bold-24 {
    @apply font-bold text-[24px] leading-[36px];
  }

  .p-medium-24 {
    @apply font-medium text-[24px] leading-[36px];
  }

  .p-regular-24 {
    @apply font-normal text-[24px] leading-[36px];
  }

  /* 20 */
  .p-bold-20 {
    @apply font-bold text-[20px] leading-[30px] tracking-[2%];
  }

  .p-semibold-20 {
    @apply text-[20px] font-semibold leading-[30px] tracking-[2%];
  }

  .p-medium-20 {
    @apply text-[20px] font-medium leading-[30px];
  }

  .p-regular-20 {
    @apply text-[20px] font-normal leading-[30px] tracking-[2%];
  }

  /* 18 */
  .p-semibold-18 {
    @apply text-[18px] font-semibold leading-[28px] tracking-[2%];
  }

  .p-medium-18 {
    @apply text-[18px] font-medium leading-[28px];
  }

  .p-regular-18 {
    @apply text-[18px] font-normal leading-[28px] tracking-[2%];
  }

  /* 16 */
  .p-bold-16 {
    @apply text-[16px] font-bold leading-[24px];
  }

  .p-medium-16 {
    @apply text-[16px] font-medium leading-[24px];
  }

  .p-regular-16 {
    @apply text-[16px] font-normal leading-[24px];
  }

  /* 14 */
  .p-semibold-14 {
    @apply text-[14px] font-semibold leading-[20px];
  }

  .p-medium-14 {
    @apply text-[14px] font-medium leading-[20px];
  }

  .p-regular-14 {
    @apply text-[14px] font-normal leading-[20px];
  }

  /* 12 */
  .p-medium-12 {
    @apply text-[12px] font-medium leading-[20px];
  }

  /* SHADCN OVERRIDES */
  .select-field {
    @apply w-full bg-grey-50 h-[54px] placeholder:text-grey-500 rounded-full p-regular-16 px-5 py-3 border-none focus-visible:ring-transparent focus:ring-transparent !important;
  }

  .input-field {
    @apply bg-grey-50 h-[54px] focus-visible:ring-offset-0 placeholder:text-grey-500 rounded-full p-regular-16 px-4 py-3 border-none focus-visible:ring-transparent !important;
  }

  .textarea {
    @apply bg-grey-50 flex flex-1 placeholder:text-grey-500 p-regular-16 px-5 py-3 border-none focus-visible:ring-transparent !important;
  }

  .button {
    @apply rounded-full h-[54px] p-regular-16;
  }

  .select-item {
    @apply py-3 cursor-pointer  focus:bg-primary-50;
  }

  .toggle-switch {
    @apply bg-gray-300 !important;
  }
}

/* ========================================== CLERK STYLES */
.cl-logoImage {
  height: 38px;
}

.cl-userButtonBox {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.cl-userButtonOuterIdentifier {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.cl-userButtonPopoverCard {
  right: 4px !important;
}

.cl-formButtonPrimary:hover,
.cl-formButtonPrimary:focus,
.cl-formButtonPrimary:active {
  background-color: #705CF7
}

/* ========================================== REACT-DATEPICKER STYLES */
.datePicker {
  width: 100%;
}

.react-datepicker__input-container input {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.react-datepicker__day--selected {
  background-color: #624cf5 !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.react-datepicker__time-list-item--selected {
  background-color: #624cf5 !important;
}
```

here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "handy-hub",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@clerk/nextjs": "^4.29.5",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-alert-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@uploadthing/react": "^6.4.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.320.0",
    "mongodb": "^6.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.1.1",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "query-string": "^8.2.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-datepicker": "^6.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.1",
    "svix": "^1.17.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.2",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "uploadthing": "^6.6.0",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^6.2.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

I am unable to run the project when i click on npm run dev.
PS: the project is also inside my C:\Users<username>\OneDrive\Desktop<foldername>\HandyHub directory, I don't why it is referring to components.json as in path "C:\components.json".

here's the components.json, which is generated by shadcn-ui installation

```
{
  "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
  "style": "default",
  "rsc": true,
  "tsx": true,
  "tailwind": {
    "config": "tailwind.config.ts",
    "css": "app/globals.css",
    "baseColor": "slate",
    "cssVariables": true,
    "prefix": ""
  },
  "aliases": {
    "components": "@/components",
    "utils": "@/lib/utils"
  }
}
```

I tried removing and reinstalling node_modules, .next folder(npm run dev) and the package.lock.json. Tried to overrite installation of shadcn-ui for components.json, still no luck.

Anyone please help me resolve this error, I am stuck for the last few days.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve Node.js: "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260643/how-to-resolve-node-js-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: So do I have to create the components.json file in the C: directory?
If yes, i tried doing that, then it asks for other similar files in the project root directory to be put up in the C: directory as well!